# Monostable and astable on breadboard

Tags: 555, breadboard

I am trying to fit all three modes on of 555 timer on a breadboard. But no matter what I do I am not able to get it to work on a single breadboard. When I move the circuits on different breadboards they work as expected. Is there something wrong with the voltage supply? I tried powering my BB with Arduino 5V  pin, but no luck.

The weird thing is that when I power up two breadboards with jumper wire the circuits still work. I would really appreciate if someone can tell me what is wrong with these circuits.

**EDIT - Added schematic**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fseYLq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT**
Here is a [link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+50%0A165+-432+0+-416+0+6+0%0AR+-368+-32+-368+-80+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-368+-32+-304+-32+0%0Aw+-304+-32+-304+32+0%0Ag+-336+160+-336+192+0%0Ar+-432+32+-432+-32+0+1000%0AR+-432+-32+-432+-64+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-432+32+-464+32+0%0Ar+-464+32+-464+128+0+10000%0Aw+-464+128+-432+128+0%0Aw+-432+96+-432+128+0%0Ac+-432+128+-432+208+0+0.000001+2.422755269119976%0Ag+-432+208+-432+256+0%0Ac+-368+160+-336+160+0+1e-8+3.333333333333337%0A162+-304+64+-256+64+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Ar+-256+64+-256+112+0+220%0Ag+-256+112+-256+160+0%0A165+-160+0+-144+0+6+0%0AR+-96+-32+-96+-64+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-96+-32+-32+-32+0%0Aw+-32+-32+-32+32+0%0Ag+-64+160+-64+192+0%0Ac+-96+160+-64+160+0+0.00001+3.3333333333264257%0As+-208+160+-176+160+0+1+true%0Ar+-176+160+-176+208+0+1000%0Ag+-208+160+-208+208+0%0AR+-176+208+-176+256+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-192+128+-192+32+0%0Aw+-192+128+-160+128+0%0Ar+-160+32+-160+-16+0+10000%0AR+-160+-16+-160+-48+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+-192+32+-160+32+0%0Ac+-96+192+-160+192+0+0.000001+-0.004995004995004998%0Ag+-96+192+-96+224+0%0A162+-32+64+16+64+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Ar+16+64+16+112+0+220%0Ag+16+112+16+144+0%0Aw+-176+160+-176+96+0%0Aw+-176+96+-160+96+0%0Aw+-160+128+-160+192+0%0A165+176+0+192+0+6+4.985609397693973%0AR+240+-32+240+-64+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+272+160+272+192+0%0As+96+96+128+96+0+1+true%0Ar+128+96+128+144+0+1000%0AR+128+144+128+176+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+96+96+96+160+0%0As+336+16+368+16+0+1+true%0Ar+336+16+336+-32+0+1000%0Aw+240+-32+336+-32+0%0Ag+368+16+368+48+0%0Aw+304+32+336+32+0%0Aw+336+32+336+16+0%0A162+304+64+352+64+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Ar+352+64+352+128+0+220%0Ag+352+128+352+160+0%0Aw+128+96+176+96+0%0Aw+-304+64+-304+320+0%0Aw+-32+64+-32+336+0%0Aw+304+64+304+336+0%0AI+-128+496+-64+496+0+0.5+5%0A150+16+416+112+416+0+2+0+5%0Aw+304+336+16+336+0%0Aw+16+336+16+368+0%0Aw+16+368+-128+368+0%0Aw+-128+368+-128+432+0%0Aw+16+368+16+400+0%0Aw+-304+320+-304+464+0%0Aw+-304+464+16+464+0%0Aw+16+464+16+432+0%0Aw+-128+432+-160+432+0%0Aw+-160+432+-160+496+0%0Aw+-160+496+-128+496+0%0A150+32+496+112+496+0+2+0+5%0Aw+-64+496+16+496+0%0Aw+16+496+16+480+0%0Aw+16+480+32+480+0%0Aw+-32+336+-208+336+0%0Aw+-208+336+-208+528+0%0Aw+-208+528+32+528+0%0Aw+32+528+32+512+0%0A152+160+448+272+448+0+2+0+5%0Aw+112+416+160+416+0%0Aw+160+416+160+432+0%0Aw+112+496+160+496+0%0Aw+160+496+160+464+0%0A150+336+432+448+432+0+2+0+5%0Aw+272+448+336+448+0%0AI+224+384+288+384+0+0.5+5%0Aw+288+384+288+416+0%0Aw+288+416+336+416+0%0A162+448+432+496+432+2+default-led+0+0+1+0.01%0Ar+496+432+496+480+0+1000%0Ag+496+480+496+512+0%0Aw+208+384+224+384+0%0AR+176+384+128+384+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0A155+1184+-16+1296+-16+0+5%0A162+1424+-48+1488+-48+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Ar+1488+-48+1536+-48+0+1000%0Ag+1536+-48+1536+-16+0%0AI+784+0+864+0+0+0.5+5%0A150+880+-32+976+-32+0+2+5+5%0A150+880+64+976+64+0+2+0+5%0A152+1008+16+1120+16+0+2+5+5%0Aw+864+0+864+-16+0%0Aw+864+-16+880+-16+0%0Aw+976+-32+976+0+0%0Aw+976+0+1008+0+0%0Aw+1120+16+1120+-16+0%0Aw+1120+-16+1184+-16+0%0Aw+1280+-16+1280+-80+0%0Aw+1280+-80+864+-80+0%0Aw+864+-80+864+-48+0%0Aw+864+-48+880+-48+0%0Aw+784+0+784+48+0%0Aw+784+48+880+48+0%0Aw+880+80+816+80+0%0Aw+976+64+976+32+0%0Aw+976+32+1008+32+0%0As+528+-64+592+-64+0+1+false%0Ar+592+-64+640+-64+0+1000%0AR+528+-64+480+-64+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0As+720+80+768+80+0+0+false%0Ar+768+80+816+80+0+1000%0AR+720+80+672+80+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+448+432+448+400+0%0Aw+448+400+544+400+0%0Aw+1184+128+1184+16+0%0A180+1360+-48+1424+-48+0+0.1+10000000000%0Aw+1280+-16+1312+-16+0%0Aw+1312+-16+1312+-48+0%0Aw+1312+-48+1360+-48+0%0A172+1392+-32+1392+0+0+7+5+5+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0A172+1408+224+1408+256+0+7+5+5+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0Aw+1328+208+1376+208+0%0Aw+1328+240+1328+208+0%0Aw+1296+240+1328+240+0%0A180+1376+208+1440+208+0+0.1+10000000000%0Aw+1200+384+1200+272+0%0Aw+992+288+1024+288+0%0Aw+992+320+992+288+0%0Aw+896+336+800+336+0%0Aw+800+304+896+304+0%0Aw+800+256+800+304+0%0Aw+880+208+896+208+0%0Aw+880+176+880+208+0%0Aw+1296+176+880+176+0%0Aw+1296+240+1296+176+0%0Aw+1136+240+1200+240+0%0Aw+1136+272+1136+240+0%0Aw+992+256+1024+256+0%0Aw+992+224+992+256+0%0Aw+880+240+896+240+0%0Aw+880+256+880+240+0%0A152+1024+272+1136+272+0+2+0+5%0A150+896+320+992+320+0+2+0+5%0A150+896+224+992+224+0+2+0+5%0AI+800+256+880+256+0+0.5+5%0Ag+1552+208+1552+240+0%0Ar+1504+208+1552+208+0+1000%0A162+1440+208+1504+208+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0A155+1200+240+1312+240+0+0%0A155+1200+512+1312+512+0+5%0A162+1440+480+1504+480+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Ar+1504+480+1552+480+0+1000%0Ag+1552+480+1552+512+0%0AI+800+528+880+528+0+0.5+5%0A150+896+496+992+496+0+2+5+5%0A150+896+592+992+592+0+2+0+5%0A152+1024+544+1136+544+0+2+5+5%0Aw+880+528+880+512+0%0Aw+880+512+896+512+0%0Aw+992+496+992+528+0%0Aw+992+528+1024+528+0%0Aw+1136+544+1136+512+0%0Aw+1136+512+1200+512+0%0Aw+1296+512+1296+448+0%0Aw+1296+448+880+448+0%0Aw+880+448+880+480+0%0Aw+880+480+896+480+0%0Aw+800+528+800+576+0%0Aw+800+576+896+576+0%0Aw+896+608+800+608+0%0Aw+992+592+992+560+0%0Aw+992+560+1024+560+0%0Aw+1200+656+1200+544+0%0A180+1376+480+1440+480+0+0.1+10000000000%0Aw+1296+512+1328+512+0%0Aw+1328+512+1328+480+0%0Aw+1328+480+1376+480+0%0A172+1408+496+1408+528+0+7+5+5+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0A172+1408+752+1408+784+0+7+5+5+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0Aw+1328+736+1376+736+0%0Aw+1328+768+1328+736+0%0Aw+1296+768+1328+768+0%0A180+1376+736+1440+736+0+0.1+10000000000%0Aw+1200+912+1200+800+0%0Aw+992+816+1024+816+0%0Aw+992+848+992+816+0%0Aw+896+864+800+864+0%0Aw+800+832+896+832+0%0Aw+800+784+800+832+0%0Aw+880+736+896+736+0%0Aw+880+704+880+736+0%0Aw+1296+704+880+704+0%0Aw+1296+768+1296+704+0%0Aw+1136+768+1200+768+0%0Aw+1136+800+1136+768+0%0Aw+992+784+1024+784+0%0Aw+992+752+992+784+0%0Aw+880+768+896+768+0%0Aw+880+784+880+768+0%0A152+1024+800+1136+800+0+2+0+5%0A150+896+848+992+848+0+2+0+5%0A150+896+752+992+752+0+2+0+5%0AI+800+784+880+784+0+0.5+5%0Ag+1552+736+1552+768+0%0Ar+1504+736+1552+736+0+1000%0A162+1440+736+1504+736+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0A155+1200+768+1312+768+0+0%0Aw+544+400+544+128+0%0Aw+544+128+1184+128+0%0Aw+1200+384+592+384+0%0Aw+544+400+592+400+0%0Aw+592+384+592+400+0%0Aw+544+400+544+656+0%0Aw+544+656+1200+656+0%0Aw+544+656+544+912+0%0Aw+544+912+1200+912+0%0Aw+640+-64+640+0+0%0Aw+640+0+784+0+0%0Aw+640+0+640+256+0%0Aw+640+256+800+256+0%0Aw+640+256+640+528+0%0Aw+800+528+640+528+0%0Aw+640+528+640+784+0%0Aw+640+784+800+784+0%0AR+704+336+656+336+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+752+336+800+336+0+1000%0As+704+336+752+336+0+1+false%0As+704+608+752+608+0+0+false%0Ar+752+608+800+608+0+1000%0AR+704+608+656+608+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0AR+704+864+656+864+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+752+864+800+864+0+1000%0As+704+864+752+864+0+1+false%0Ax+504+-88+557+-85+4+24+Load%0Ax+-405+-107+-315+-104+4+24+A%5CsStable%0Ax+-135+-103+-11+-100+4+24+Monostable%0Ax+218+-100+311+-97+4+24+Bi-stable%0Aw+96+96+96+32+0%0Aw+96+32+176+32+0%0Ag+176+176+176+224+0%0Aw+176+128+176+176+0%0Ac+240+160+240+208+0+1.0000000000000001e-7+3.333333333333236%0Aw+176+176+240+208+0%0Ao+91+64+0+4099+5+0.025+0+2+91+3%0Ao+11+64+0+4099+5+0.0015625+1+2+11+3%0A) to what I am trying.

[image: Timers]

Comment: Please, add a schematic of your circuit. You can edit the question and add it using the built-in tool.

Comment: please describe exactly what happens when all three circuits are on one breadboard

Comment: *Is there something wrong with the voltage supply?* Did you measure it?

Comment: @jDAQ added schematic.

Comment: @jsotola when I have all three circuits on the bread board only the first from left works. but if I move them to different breadboards all of them work.

Comment: @Huisman I tested the voltage on the second circuit on the Vcc pin and it shows 5v. but on the output pin its 0v. In the image the first circuit is monostable and it works. but when I move it down and move the astable in the first position the astable starts working but the monostable doesn't

Comment: Please double check your schematic. I don't believe you use current sources (I1 and I2) and I think R4 should be 390Ω

Comment: @Nilesh, remove the `first from the left` circuit ... do the other two start to work?

Comment: @jsotola never tried that as it was not working with the two. But I will try it today.

Comment: I was able to get Monostable and astable working side by side. Apparently you cannot rely on breadboards to do a solid connection and a solid 9v battery also helped. There is always a possibility of some loose wire make you bang your head against the wall. I still have the problem with Bistable and it does not seem like a loose connection. But I will get it working. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for delay in response. Seems like the breadboard that I was using was not working as expected, it definitely was not making solid contact with the components and jumpers. So I purchased new breadboards and made sure all the components made solid connections and finally it worked. I still face some glitch when I add more components and power couple of more breadboards together with a 9v power supply, but that is different issue. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Oft times, breadboards like that have a break in the power rails at their midpoint, easily resolved with a jumper to connect the halves. Check yours with a meter. Also, need to jumper + and - from left-hand rail to the right hand rail. Yours don't appear to be connected in the posted picture.

Comment: You can usually tell by looking at those red and blue lines that run on either side of the power rails. If there is a break in the middle of the rail, there should also be a break in the middle of the line. At least, if my memory is correct.

Comment: I think that's not the case. cause I have powered the breadboard from the right and there are jumper + and - connecting both power rails which is not in the image. and when I put just an LED on the right it lights up only when it gets to the astable timer circuit it doesn't work. I will try to post additional images today with both circuits working  on different breadboards.

Comment: @Nilesh "*...which is not in the image*" Make sure to show a **complete** image. The more/better information you provide, the higher the chance you get a useful answer.

Comment: @Huisman agreed. Let me go back and upload a full image.